# Does capacitor have a WEB-VIEW under the hood?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor

I have been creating apps with ionic for a few years now. As capacitor has now replaced Apache cordova, which was based on a web view, I was wondering weather Capacitor does the same?

If yes, then how is it any different from apache cordova in terms of performance as the limitations of the web view will still imply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Yeah both Apache Cordova and Capacitor are based on a web-view however capacitors web-view is made in house by Ionic most likely a stripped down version webkit. So there may be a performance benefit for Capacitor as they'll be able to remove unnecessary features from the ios and android web-view. The main real difference is how they access/build the native functionality whereas Cordova packages most of it away and attempts to do everything itself to varying success, Capacitor will let you work with the Android Manifest/Info.plist/etc. Capacitor also has the advantage of giving the Ionic team full control of the development environment which should mean if there are issues their team can fix it quickly.

It seems more about giving more development freedom and reliability than performance.